# gRPC.Net DeadlineExceeded errors on client streaming side but server logs no errors

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-7.0

I'm trying to give gRPC.Net a go as I have a requirement for sending high volume data (application logs) from 4 servers. The problem I am constantly getting is that I can leave everything running with all 4 servers (grpc client) sending their data to my logging server (grpc server), but I come into work the next day and I find errors, with some of the clients disconnected and unable to reconnect.

The 4 servers are running linux with nginx and each has an asp.net core app running using kestral. This app has the GRPC client.

The server is a windows server running a web app in kestral. This has the GRPC server.

I left the grpc logging enabled ("GRPC": "Debug") on the server app running over night and today I found the following between 1 of the clients and the server.

Linux Server (Grpc Client)

> [2023-02-20 20:51:38.671  INF] (.)-Creating Client
> [2023-02-20 20:51:38.672  INF] (.)-Creating Call
> [2023-02-20 20:51:42.526  INF] (.)-Creating Client
> [2023-02-20 20:51:42.527  INF] (.)-Creating Call
> [2023-02-20 20:51:42.835  INF] (.)-Creating Client
> [2023-02-20 20:51:42.835  INF] (.)-Creating Call
> [2023-02-20 20:52:27.769  INF] (.)-Creating Client
> [2023-02-20 20:52:27.770  INF] (.)-Creating Call
> [2023-02-20 20:53:27.780  WRN] (Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall.)-gRPC call deadline exceeded.
> [2023-02-20 20:53:27.796  INF] (Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall.)-Call failed with gRPC error status. Status code: '"DeadlineExceeded"', Message: ''.
> [2023-02-20 20:53:27.801  ERR] (.)-Error in streaming
> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="")
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.  <<ClientStreamWriteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.DoClientStreamActionAsync(Func`2 action)   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.DoClientStreamActionAsync(Func`2 action)   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.ClientStreamWriteAsync(TRequest message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at WebApi.Services.Hosted.LogSender.b__9_0()
> [2023-02-20 20:53:27.919  INF] (.)-Creating Client
> [2023-02-20 20:53:27.919  INF] (.)-Creating Call
> [2023-02-20 20:54:27.936  WRN] (Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall.)-gRPC call deadline exceeded.
> [2023-02-20 20:54:27.939  ERR] (.)-Error in streaming
> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="")
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.  <<ClientStreamWriteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.DoClientStreamActionAsync(Func`2 action)   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.DoClientStreamActionAsync(Func`2 action)   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.Retry.RetryCall`2.ClientStreamWriteAsync(TRequest message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at WebApi.Services.Hosted.LogSender.b__9_0()

Eventually I get this.

> [2023-02-20 22:02:36.302  INF] (Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall.)-Call failed with gRPC error status. Status code: '"Unavailable"', Message: 'Error connecting to subchannel.'.
> [2023-02-20 22:02:37.173  ERR] (Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall.)-Error starting gRPC call.
> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|281_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.SocketConnectivitySubchannelTransport.TryConnectAsync(ConnectContext context)")
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager.PickAsync(PickContext context, Boolean waitForReady, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)

Those errors carry on and it never recovers.
I checked the server logs and it reports no errors what so ever, yet if I restart the Grpc server app, the client then recovers and connects.

On the client side I have the Grpc running in a service and the Grpc is created in the constructor of the service.

```
private GrpcChannel CreateGrpcChannel()
    {
        LocalLogger.Log.Information("Creating the Grpc Channel");

        var defaultMethodConfig = new MethodConfig
        {
            Names = { MethodName.Default },
            RetryPolicy = new RetryPolicy
            {
                MaxAttempts = 5,
                InitialBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                MaxBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                BackoffMultiplier = 1.5,
                RetryableStatusCodes = { StatusCode.Unavailable, StatusCode.Aborted, StatusCode.DeadlineExceeded, StatusCode.ResourceExhausted, StatusCode.Unknown }
            }
        };

        var options = new GrpcChannelOptions
        {
            HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan,
                KeepAlivePingDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                KeepAlivePingTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true
            },
            MaxReceiveMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxSendMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            LoggerFactory = new SerilogLoggerFactory(LocalLogger.Log),
            ServiceConfig = new ServiceConfig { MethodConfigs = { defaultMethodConfig } }
        };

        return GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://myserver.com:5050", options);
    }
```

and the actual streaming happens here

```
                if (_events.Any())
                {
                    LocalLogger.Log.Information("Creating Client");

                    client = new Logger.LoggerClient(channel);                        

                    LocalLogger.Log.Information("Creating Call");

                    LogEvent logEventToSend = null;

                    try
                    {

                        using var call = client.StreamingLogFromClient(deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60));
                        {
                            while (_events.Any())
                            {
                                if (_events.TryDequeue(out logEventToSend))
                                {
                                    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new LogRequest()
                                    {
                                        LogEvent = logEventToSend
                                    });

                                    logEventToSend = null;
                                }
                            }

                            await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
                            _ = await call;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        if(logEventToSend is not null)
                        {
                            // log didn't send so put it back on the queue
                            _events.Enqueue(logEventToSend);
                        }

                        LocalLogger.Log.Error(ex, "Error in streaming");
                    }

                    client = null;
                }
```

All running with .Net 7

Comment: Does using a new GrpcChannel help (e.g. recreating the channel from time to time, e.g every 10mins help?).

Comment: Also, do you have logic that starts a new client streaming RPC when the existing call fails? Generally the RPC shouldn't be expected to "live forever" - e.g. if no data is sent for a while, the underlying TCP connection might get disconnected (which is to some extent solvable with keepalive, but you still need logic to restart a long lived RPC).

Comment: Also, I'd try running the client without the retry functionality enabled and see if that changes the behavior (and have your application logic recreate the RPC when it fails - you need that logic anyway since when your application runs for long enough, you'll run out of retry MaxAttempts anyway, so it seems that using auto retries for long-lived streaming RPC isn't that useful).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan, so the issue seems more related to the server side. 
What I was noticing was that if I saw an issue and restarted the client app, I still got the error. It's only when restarting the server app did the issue resolve.
I have now set the server app to restart every 24hours and so far no issue has returned. 

I have taken note of a few things you have said regarding the client and long running RPC.